# Difference between 'sed -i' and 'sed ... > file'

Tags: linux, sed

I would like to know the difference between these two lines :

```
sudo sed 's/GRUB_TIMEOUT=10/GRUB_TIMEOUT=3/' /etc/default/grub >/etc/default/grub
```

and

```
sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_TIMEOUT=10/GRUB_TIMEOUT=3/' /etc/default/grub
```

There seems to be a difference because the first returns a Permission denied error while the other doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @sarathi said, the `-i` flag modifies the file in-place. The reason you're getting a permission denied error is because `/etc/default/grub` is probably only modifiable by root.

Your first command:

```
sudo sed 's/GRUB_TIMEOUT=10/GRUB_TIMEOUT=3/' /etc/default/grub >/etc/default/grub
```

Runs `sed` as a superuser, which doesn't do anything useful as `sed` writes to its stdout. Then it tries to overwrite `/etc/default/grub` as the current user, which is disallowed.

In the second command:

```
sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_TIMEOUT=10/GRUB_TIMEOUT=3/' /etc/default/grub
```

The file is modified by `sed` itself, which is running as root.

Comment: Actually with `>` shell first tries to open `/etc/default/grub` for writing and fails. It probably doesn't even start `sed` or `sudo`.

Comment: And if it did work, it would result in an empty file; the truncation of the output file occurs before `sed` gets to read any input from it.

Answer (score 1):

`-i` flag of sed says inplace replacement.